# I want to convert an Object with a java.time.Localdate (JSR-310) to XML via JAXB but the output is wrong

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-8, java-time

I want to convert an Object with a java.time.Localdate (JSR-310) and a property wrapping a Localdate to XML via JAXB but the output is wrong.

```
public <T> void printPdf(T obj) {
    // create xml
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
    m.marshal(obj, result);

    StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer();
    String finalstring = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(finalstring);
}
```

This is the Object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Invoice implements Validateable {
    private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dueDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(20));
    // ========================================================================
    // date
    // ========================================================================
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    // ========================================================================
    // companyName
    // ========================================================================
    public LocalDate getDueDate() {
        return this.dueDate.get();
    }
    public void setDueDate(LocalDate duedate) {
        this.dueDate.set(duedate);
    }
    public final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dueDateProperty() {
        return dueDate;
    }
}
```

This is the XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<invoice>
    <date/>
    <dueDate/>
</invoice>
```

How can I convert this properly? I'm not stuck to use JAXB if there is something better out there.

Comment: same subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251183/can-jaxb-handle-java-time-objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JAXB `XmlAdapter` to control how the JSR-310 objects are converted to/from XML.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html